# What are the differences between "You always dress in a black suit" and "You are always dressed in a black suit" in spoken language?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

[In this dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dress_2), "**dress**" can have 2 meanings

> -**Dress** [intransitive, transitive] to put clothes on yourself/somebody:
>
> dress (in something) I dressed quickly.
>
> dress somebody (in something) She dressed the children in their best
>   clothes.
>
> Get up and get dressed!
>
> The children spend hours dressing and undressing their dolls.
>
> -**Dress** [intransitive, transitive] to wear a particular type or style of clothes:
>
> to dress well/badly/fashionably/comfortably:
>
> dress for/in/as something You should dress for cold weather today. She
>   always dressed entirely in black.
>
> dress somebody (for/in/as something) He was dressed as a woman (= he
>   was wearing women's clothes).

But [this site](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dress) says

-When talking about wearing a specific clothes

Though we can say "**I dress in a black suit**" ("dress" is an intransitive verb in this case). But, in spoken language, normally we do not say like that but say "**I am dressed in a black suit**"

-When talking about a particular type of clothes, we use "dress" as an intransitive verb

*She's over 40, but she still dresses like a teenager*

*He needs to change the way he dresses.*

"to dress for winter"

So, in spoken language, what are the differences between "**You always dress in a black suit**" and "**You are always dressed in a black suit**"?

So, does "**You always dress in a black suit**" emphasize that you wear a particular type of clothes?

Does "**You are always dressed in a black suit**" emphasize that you wear  specific clothes?

Comment: There's not really a dime's worth of difference between them. For the most part, they're just different ways to say the same thing. Whatever nuances you fancy may exist are almost certainly not noticed in oral communication.

Comment: Please read the usage note once again, carefully. "If you want to describe someone's clothes on a particular occasion..." doesn't (just) emphasize "wearing specific clothes", for example. *Specific* and *particular* are synonymous, by the way, and *clothes* is a plural noun.

Comment: There's no difference between _"You always dress in a black suit"_ and _"You're always dressed in a black suit"_. Note the contraction, which is the way it would actually be spoken.  ("Clothes" is a _plurale tantum_. It has no singular form. It can never take the indefinite article, only the definite or zero article. We can never say _**"a clothes."**_)

Comment: Your citation from the Free Dictionary concerns the _translation_ of one of the senses _to dress_ as the Spanish _vestir_.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, then tell me why most people say "**I am married**" though "**to marry**" is either "transitive" or "intransitive". "**I married**" is not wrong

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say here. Of course there is nothing "wrong" with the statement _"I married"_, but without an _object_, the statement is as meaningless as the statement _"I dressed"_, which is also not "wrong". Do you understand the difference between the terms _transitive_ and _intransitive_? Yours is a common problem among students of English who have no experience of hearing and speaking the language in real life, among real people. As you gain that experience, your misunderstandings will disappear.

Comment: @P.E.Dant, you didn't understand what I said. I meant most people would say "I am married", very few would say "I married". The same thing applies to "dress". "I am dressed in a skirt" is more common than "I dress in a skirt".

Comment: Well, _"I dress in a skirt"_ and _"I am dressed in a skirt"_ have completely different meanings, and would be said in completely different contexts. **Q**: _What do you you wear for that performance?_ **A**: _I dress in a skirt._

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, **You always dress in a black suit** looks pretty equivalent to **You are always dressed in a black suit**, with the apparent meaning being "You always wear a black suit".  A number of people commented that they are the same.  In fact, both constructions are in common usage.  You might even hear cases of the constructions being used interchangeably.  However, they are actually different, and when used properly, they are used differently, and with a different nuance in meaning.

The main source of confusion is in viewing the difference between the sentences as relating to different tenses of the verb "dress".  In fact, there is discussion in the comments that "are dressed" is simply passive construction.  I'll explain how and why the sentences are different, and how the usage is different when speakers are not being sloppy with the language. <sup>[1]</sup>

The gist of the difference stems from this: **you dress...** describes a habit, **you are dressed...** describes a present example or observation of the habit.

**Tense**

Lets focus first on tense and consider a simplified example:

- **You were dressed in black** explicitly describes something in the past.
- **You are dressed in black** explicitly describes something in the present.
- **You will be dressed in black** explicitly describes something in the future,
- **You dress in black** is simple present, which is not anchored to the present time.  *"The principal use of the simple present is to refer to an action or event that takes place habitually."* (See [Wikipedia discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_present))

**You always dress in a black suit**

Simple present "dress" is the verb, and this describes your habit.  It would be said by someone familiar enough with your routine to know that it's what you always do.  It could refer to what you're currently wearing, but it could also be said in a context that doesn't involve that person actually seeing you, and it could refer to any time frame.

For example, you could be having a telephone conversation with the person discussing what you should wear at an upcoming event.

> You: "What should I wear?"
>   Other person: "You always dress in a black suit."

That's a comment about your habit.  The meaning would depend on the context of the discussion and the intonation of the words.  It could be a suggestion to wear what you usually wear, or it could be a suggestion to wear something other than what you usually wear.

Notice that this construction has no inherent positive or negative connotation.  In addition to the positive and negative examples above, it can be used with no value connotation at all, simply a statement of fact.

**You are always dressed in a black suit**

As similar as this sentence seems, it is actually a different beast.  I'll break it down.  Consider this sentence:

> You are tall.

"Tall" is an adjective describing "you".  "Are" is the verb.  Now replace "tall":

> You are [dressed in a black suit].

In this construction, "dressed" is not the past tense of the verb "dress", it is an adjective, part of an adjective phrase that describes "you".  By coincidence the [Macmillan Dictionary definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dressed) of "dressed" as an adjective uses this as an example: *"She was dressed in a black suit."*  What are the odds of that coincidence?

So "dressed" does not contribute a tense, it is not a past participle verb, and it is not part of an "are dressed" passive construction.  The only verb in the sentence is "are", and as in the discussion under Tense, it explicitly describes something in the present.  The present is one example, or an observation of one example, of the habit.

"Always" indicates that it is something recurring and routine, as in "You **always** say that".  "Always" in combination with "are" refers to a recurring pattern or series of then-present events.  These are examples or observations of the habit.

This is the perspective of an observer.  The observer sees a collection of then-present examples, which for the observer, is a pattern of observations.  This construction is a generic reference to the observations of the habit rather than the habit, itself.

It would most likely be said by someone observing you and commenting on your present attire.  It would typically mean:

> Every time I see you, you are wearing a black suit.

It is a reference to their observations of you rather than to what you wear when they don't see you.

This construction is different from simple present in terms of the usual positive/negative connotations of its use.  It is rarely used with a positive connotation.  It can be used in a neutral way, but it tends to be used with a negative (or sarcastic) connotation.

Going back to the telephone discussion of attire for a future event, this construction could also be used there, but in a slightly different context.     It would also reflect the perspective of the observer more than your habit.  The two constructions:

1. You: "I think I'll wear a black suit."
   Other person: "You always dress in a black suit."
   This is a reference to your habit and a suggestion to change it for this event.
2. You: "I think I'll wear a black suit."
   Other person: "You are always dressed in a black suit."
   The perspective of this comment is that a black suit is what other people always see you in and a suggestion to let them see you in something different.

   ---

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>*Many thanks to [Ben Kovitz](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/6700/ben-kovitz) for identifying the language principles underlying the "why".*</sub>

Comment: You are drawing a distinction without a difference. Any of those statements may be said in any context, and suggest any of the meanings. How is "your routine attire" different at all from "the practice [of dress] you follow"?

Comment: @Robusto, I didn't understand your comment, or maybe I didn't write what I intended to say in the answer clearly.  "your routine attire" and "the practice of dress you follow" wasn't something I was intending to distinguish.  I see "you always dress..." as more describing the person's practices, and "you are always dressed..." as more the observation of it by the speaker.  I'm not saying English language defines it that way, just that those perspectives would be more associated with how people typically use the constructions.

Comment: I agree either would be grammatically correct and there's nothing to preclude people from using either in either situation. Both sentences refer to "your routine attire", as mentioned in the first paragraph, so to that extent, they mean the same thing.  The rest of the answer was distinguishing a nuance of perspective; the context in which each would more likely be used.

Comment: "You always dress in a black suit" and "You are always dressed in a black suit" differ only in that the latter is a passive construction. Otherwise they say exactly the same thing. I'm sorry you went to all this trouble to expound on supposed differences between the two in your answer, but I'm afraid those differences don't exist in the real world.

Comment: @Robusto, they exist in my world, maybe I don't live in the real world.  :-)  I'd be curious to get feedback from others as to whether anyone else sees the same thing.

Comment: I think this is exactly right: "You always dress…" emphasizes the dresser's
habit or volition; "You are always dressed…" emphasizes observation or mere
repeated occurrence. (Very hard to sort out!) The idea that emphasis or
perspective makes no difference because the situation is still the same, is a
fallacy. It's also a mistake to think that the difference between active and
passive is solely syntactic—and also a mistake to think that "are dressed…" is
passive here.

Comment: Perhaps you could make the answer more useful and maybe answer the critics
by explaining why it works this way, with other verbs or tenses. For example,
with linking verbs, the simple present refers to the present moment, but with
most verbs, the simple present takes the action or state out of time, and
consequently is the tense of choice for "[fundamental attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_attribution_error)".

Comment: Coming up with good examples sounds like a lot of work, though! One idea: "He
saves money" vs. "He is saving money" (habit/volition vs. right now); "He
always saves money" vs. "He is always saving money" (continuous/regular
habit/volition vs. intermittent but frequent opportunism).
Another possible approach: "Tomorrow I will dress in a black suit"
vs. "Tomorrow I will be dressed in a black suit." Maybe also "You have always
dressed in a black suit" vs. "You have always been dressed in a black suit."

Comment: @BenKovitz, thanks for the great feedback.  I'll have to give this some more thought (and steal your ideas).  :-)

Comment: One more idea came to mind: "You dress…" means that you (habitually) engage in the action that results in the state asserted by "You are dressed…" More examples: "You always get drunk" vs. "You are always drunk"; "You always rest" vs. "You are always rested"; "You always prepare" vs. "You are always prepared." The present participle might help illustrate the habitual/momentary idea, too: "You wear a uniform" vs. "You are wearing a uniform"; "You always wear a uniform" vs. "You are always wearing a uniform." The latter seems less solid, more open to making an exception.

Comment: You really ought to look up "passive construction" before making pronouncements. That aside, go ahead and torture logic all you want.

Comment: @Robusto, my perception is that "dressed in a black suit" serves as an adjective phrase and "was" is the main verb, rather than "was dressed" being passive construction.  I did some cleanup on the answer.  I suspect we're not going to agree on this one, but I appreciate your input and learned some stuff in researching your comments.  So thanks.

Comment: @Robusto, "dressed: **adjective**: 1. wearing clothes of a particular type.  ex: **She was dressed in a black suit.**"  [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dressed).  Talk about coincidence.  So not passive construction.

Comment: I don't think you understand passive constructions yet ...

Answer (score -1):

Both can mean rougly the same thing: Every time I see you, I notice that you wear a black suit. With some little differences, as explained in fixer1234's answer.

But "You are always dressed in a black suit" has another, totally different second meaning. It means "Wearing a black suit makes anybody look well-dressed". Or "One is always well-dressed when wearing a black suit". For example: "I should really look my best on Joe's wedding. What should I wear"? Answer: "You are always dressed in a black suit".